# Is Visual C++ Redistributables backward compatible?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am including two programs in my software. One of which requires VC10 and the other requires VC11. My question is that if program developed for VC10 will work on VC11 or I have to include both VC10 and VC11

Comment: Yes it will be fine - been there, done that myself. I don't want to give such as short statement as answer so passed on as a comment.

Comment: Not sure what what that "yes" comment signifies, but the answers, as given below, is that you'll have to include both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried running a software designed for VC10 in a fresh installation of windows 7 in virtual box with only VC11 installed and it doesn't work. It worked later after I installed VC10.

Hence, the short asnswer is:

**No**

Comment: Even point updates within VC10 and VC11 don't work well within one another.  The general rule that always works is if you use VC++ Redistrubutables provide the same version you developed against.  This way if its missing it will be installed.  This is what Steam does and it seems to work.  This can be added onto anything that you had to install in order to develope against.